# d3 zoom on a specific country (hardcoded)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this d3 map:

```
var svg = d3.select(mapRef.current)
      .append("svg")
      .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid")
      .attr("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height)
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

var g = svg.append("g");

g.append("g")
        .attr("id", "countries")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(values[0], values[0].objects.countries).features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
        .attr("d", path);
```

and on svg click trying to zoom on a specific (hardcoded) country (eg France).
any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Example of zoom to bounding box of a specific feature: https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoom-to-bounding-box

Comment: thanks @RobinMackenzie! i just can't get it to work with a hardcoded country/state.